# How are "Starless: 21st Century Nymphomaniacs" and "Sleepless: A Midsummer Night's Dream - The Animation" anime or visual novels related?

Tags: visual-novel-production

**NSFW Warning: this question is related to hentai anime and VN.**

MyAnimeList says *Starless: 21st Century Nymphomaniacs* is the prequel of *Sleepless: A Midsummer Night's Dream - The Animation*. They both have the same characters Mamiya Marie and her daughters. And yep, VNDB says they are adapted from the same visual novel series. But I don't see how they are related. I mean, what could've happened between the stories in these two anime?

In *Sleepless*, it's revealed that the private tutors hired by the mistress would be dismembered, then what became of the MC in *Starless*? Was he dismembered? In *Starless*, there are more than one maids in the mansion, but in *Sleepless*, there's only one, what became of the others?